# Show a Progress bar while performing ComboBox tasks

Tags: wpf, powershell

When an item is selected in a ComboBox, some files are copied which match the selected name. This takes some time and the screen is just frozen (with the list dropped down) during that time, I would like the dropped down combobox list to go up and a show a Progress Bar while the files get copied. I tried adding a Progress Bar but it doesn't show up.

```
$ComboBox.Add_SelectionChanged(
{
    $progressBar.Visibility = "Visible"     #Show an Indeterminate Progress Bar at the beginning
    
    if($ComboBox.SelectedItem)
    {
        $selectedName = $ComboBox.SelectedItem
        Copy-Item -Path $storePath\* -Destination $tempPath -Filter $selectedName*
        $fileList = (Get-ChildItem -Path $tempPath).Name | Select-String $selectedName

        $ListBox.Items.Clear()
        foreach($file in $fileList)
        {
            $ListBox.Items.Add($fileList)
        }
    }
    
    $progressBar.Visibility = "Hidden"      #Hide the Progress Bar once done
})
```

Comment: You need to add another element for that and you need to do the math on the expected collection. So, you have to collect what you need to count for the progress to work. There are several examples of this on the web and via Youtube videos.   ['''add progressbar to your powershell form'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=add+progressbar+to+your+powershell+form&t=h_&ia=web)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I used 'DropDownClosed' to trigger the Copy, while using 'SelectionChanged' to trigger the Progress Bar. The problem now is that the Progress Bar gets stuck. Now I need another way to run the ProgressBar in a separate Thread.

```
$ComboBox.Add_SelectionChanged(
{
    $progressBar.Visibility = "Visible"     #Show an Indeterminate Progress Bar at the beginning
})

$ComboBox.Add_DropDownClosed(
{
    if($ComboBox.SelectedItem)
    {
        $selectedName = $ComboBox.SelectedItem
        
        if(!((Get-ChildItem -Path $tempPath).Name | Select-String $selectedName))
        {
            Copy-Item -Path $storePath\* -Destination $tempPath -Filter $selectedName*
        }
        
        $fileList = (Get-ChildItem -Path $tempPath).Name | Select-String $selectedName

        $ListBox.Items.Clear()
        foreach($file in $fileList)
        {
            $ListBox.Items.Add($fileList)
        }
    }
    
    $progressBar.Visibility = "Hidden"      #Hide the Progress Bar once done
})
```